# Using wp-cli to Update WP Networks / Multisite from 3.5.1 to 3.8

Tags: updates, wp-cli

I've been handed a WP Networks site that is running WP (Networks) 3.5.1 on RHEL 5.8 with about 40 sites attached to it. I see the need to update to 3.8.

By background, I'm more familiar with maintaining Drupal sites with `Drush`. My first hunch here is to use `wp-cli` to run the update.

Is this the preferred update method in the WP community or am I better swapping out php files from the tar ball? That is, can I depend on `wp-cli` to run a clean update from 3.5.1 to 3.8?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For regular users, the preferred update method is pressing the "Update" button in wp-admin.

For sysadmins, `wp core update` + `wp core update-db` will probably be a lot faster. Note that for multisite instances, you'll have to update the DB for each site in the network. See https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/683

NB: I might be biased, since I'm currently the maintainer of WP-CLI.

Comment: To confirm, at first I'd issue a `$ wp plugin update --all` from the webroot (/var/www/html). Let that download uploaded plug-ins. After, that use the [bash for loop](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/683#issuecomment-22771135) to update individual databases?

Comment: @Richard `wp core update-db` only covers Core modifications to the DB. For plugins to update their settings across the network, you'd need to do more work. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28694